# Execute Batch file on Windows 7 Remotly?

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file, remote-access

How can i launch a batch file on Windows 7 in a network environment remotely. I have admin rights on the system. Can someone please give me some idea?

Comment: voting to migrate to Serverfault

Comment: why did you voted me as negative? wana be gurus!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serverfault is probably better place for this question but in any case, you can use psexec from sysinternals.

Here is the link for that executable.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553

Comment: thank you i did not know about serverfault. I will further refer to that.